# Finding threshold limits in image processing

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

As stated in the help section of Stackoverflow that one can ask about a "software algorithm," I believe this question is on topic. I'm viewing the following algorithm and I'm having a hard time understanding the why it is being used. I've explained the mechanics below. The code was pulled from the following [github repo](https://github.com/fu-malaria/fu-malaria).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys


def calc_sloop_change(histo, mode, tolerance):
    sloop = 0
    for i in range(0, len(histo)):
       if histo[i] > max(1, tolerance):
          sloop = i
          return sloop
       else:
          sloop = i


def process(inpath, outpath, tolerance):
    original_image = cv2.imread(inpath)
    tolerance = int(tolerance) * 0.01

    #Get properties
    width, height, channels = original_image.shape

    color_image = original_image.copy()

    blue_hist = cv2.calcHist([color_image], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
    green_hist = cv2.calcHist([color_image], [1], None, [256], [0, 256])
    red_hist = cv2.calcHist([color_image], [2], None, [256], [0, 256])

    blue_mode = blue_hist.max()
    blue_tolerance = np.where(blue_hist == blue_mode)[0][0] * tolerance
    green_mode = green_hist.max()
    green_tolerance = np.where(green_hist == green_mode)[0][0] * tolerance
    red_mode = red_hist.max()
    red_tolerance = np.where(red_hist == red_mode)[0][0] * tolerance

    sloop_blue = calc_sloop_change(blue_hist, blue_mode, blue_tolerance)
    sloop_green = calc_sloop_change(green_hist, green_mode, green_tolerance)
    sloop_red = calc_sloop_change(red_hist, red_mode, red_tolerance)

    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray_hist = cv2.calcHist([original_image], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

    largest_gray = gray_hist.max()
    threshold_gray = np.where(gray_hist == largest_gray)[0][0]

    #Red cells
    gray_image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 85, 4)

    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    c2 = [i for i in contours if cv2.boundingRect(i)[3] > 15]
    cv2.drawContours(color_image, c2, -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cp = [cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.015 * cv2.arcLength(i, True), True) for i in c2]

    countRedCells = len(c2)

    for c in cp:
       xc, yc, wc, hc = cv2.boundingRect(c)
       cv2.rectangle(color_image, (xc, yc), (xc + wc, yc + hc), (0, 255, 0), 1)

    #Malaria cells
    gray_image = cv2.inRange(original_image, np.array([sloop_blue, sloop_green, sloop_red]), np.array([255, 255, 255]))

    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray_image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    c2 = [i for i in contours if cv2.boundingRect(i)[3] > 8]
    cv2.drawContours(color_image, c2, -1, (0, 0, 0), 1)

    cp = [cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.15 * cv2.arcLength(i, True), True) for i in c2]

    countMalaria = len(c2)

    for c in cp:
       xc, yc, wc, hc = cv2.boundingRect(c)
       cv2.rectangle(color_image, (xc, yc), (xc + wc, yc + hc), (0, 0, 0), 1)

    #Write image
    cv2.imwrite(outpath, color_image)

    #Write statistics
    with open(outpath + '.stats', mode='w') as f:
       f.write(str(countRedCells) + '\n')
       f.write(str(countMalaria) + '\n')
```

The above code looks at images of cells(irregular shapes) and identifies if there are black spots /blobs inside them. Then, it draws contours around the cells and blobs. For example: [image]

I don't understand why the algorithm works the following way:

**Let me illustrate with an example:** 
Let's say my tolerance passed into `process()` is 50. Let's say `blue_hist` returns an array [1, 2, 3, 4, 100, 0, ..., 0] and the largest value in this array is 100 at index 4. This indicates that there are a 100 pixels with an intensity of 4 in the gray scale version of the color image when just the blue signal is extracted. In this situation, the function `where(blue_hist = blue_mode)` will return `4`. This value is multiplied by `0.01*tolerance` giving us `2`.

So, if the value `4` is pixel intensity value then multiplying it by a scalar only gives another pixel intensity value (in our case, `(4 * (0.01*50)) = 2`. This new pixel intensity is passed into `calc_sloop_change()`. In this function, compares `histo[i]` which returns the number of pixels at intensity `i` with tolerance(which is the pixel value we calculated earlier). So in our case, the first value greater than 2 happens when `i=3`. So `3` is returned.

**This is where I'm confused.** Why is this being done? It seems illogical to compare the number of pixels vs pixel intensity. They are not even the same entity. So, why are they using this algorithm? I must add that this code actually performs really well. So something must be right.

Lastly, the three values calculated by `calc_sloop_change()`, one for each color signal, acts as a lower cutoff to produce a binary image. Anything less than those values(which are actually pixel intensity values) becomes black and everything above those values becomes white.

Comment: Yeah, that piece of the algorithm doesn't really seem to make much sense, and works by accident.

Comment: My current thoughts exactly.

Comment: It would kinda expect it should be `blue_tolerance = blue_mode * tolerance` rather than what's there now.

Comment: @DanMašek is there a way to garner more attention to this question?

Comment: Wouldn't read too much into it, the code looks fairly sloppy TBH. It's hard to tell how well it works without good sample set -- one image doesn't cut it. I guess the tolerance parameter allowed trial and error to reach something. Most of the image is bright and the malaria cells are dark and few. The histogram is relatively flat for a while, and then it peaks sharply when you get it cell or background intensities. In this case it hovers below ~ 50, and then shoots up to >2000 over a few bins. So threshold of 100+-25 works reasonably well. The peaks are at high intensities >200. ...

Comment: So 50% of that will fall within the "reasonably well" range. You could just hardcode the threshold and it most likely wouldn't make much difference.

Comment: In the repo, they have examples of ~50 images. Thanks so much for your input though. If there are any alternative algorithms for doing something like this, I'd love to know.

Comment: Can you point me to the location, please? I haven't managed to find them yet.

Comment: There is a link provided in the `readme` section: http://fumalaria.visimagic.com/